# Complus error (Event ID 4689) on server (IIS)

Tags: iis, com

Yesterday I started getting server too busy errors on some websites we are hosting on our webserver. So I logged on the server and took a look at the event viewer

About 4 times / minute im getting this error:

> Log Name : Application
>
> Source : Complus
>
> Event ID : 4689

Error message:

> The run-time environment has detected an inconsistency in its internal state. This indicates a potential instability in the process that could be caused by the custom components running in the COM+ application, the components they make use of, or other factors. Error in d:\longhorn\com\complus\src\comsvcs\threads\stathread.cpp(300), hr = 80070008: CSTAThread: CoGetApartmentID failed

I am wondering if anyone ever got that kind of issue and if yes what is it related to / how can I fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this makes any sense to you, COM+ is just like DBUS, it allows different applications to communicate internally with each other. It appears that you have a problem with an interprocess communication.

I did manage to find this link, [COM+ The run-time environment has detected an inconsistency in its internal state.](https://web.archive.org/web/20120502185113/https://msmvps.com/blogs/alvin/archive/2008/04/07/com-the-run-time-environment-has-detected-an-inconsistency-in-its-internal-state.aspx)

Which indicates that you should change a registry setting from:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems\Windows --> SharedSection = 1024,3072,512
```

To:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\SubSystems\Windows --> SharedSection = 1024,3072,1024
```

It appears that you have run out of memory. At least your heap has been filled. This is one of those pesky errors that isn't quite programming and isn't quite system administration.

Tons more info over at another link: [Desktop Heap Overview](http://blogs.msdn.com/ntdebugging/archive/2007/01/04/desktop-heap-overview.aspx).

PS After making this change, you will probably need to reboot the server.

Comment: ty for the help i will ask out IT to take a look at the registery